# Point own subdomain to Heroku app through HTTPS

Tags: ssl, subdomain, cname-record, heroku

I have a domain, let's say *mywebsite.com* bought on NameCheap.
I have pointed it's primary and secondary DNS to my hosting provider, so I can view my website and manage the subdomains there.

I also have a wildcard SSL certificate on my webserver, so I can support all subdomains and the root domain with a single cert.

Now, I have an app on Heroku, which has a built-in SSL certificate from Heroku. It's name is app.herokuapp.com. I've created a custom domain on Heroku, which is:

**Domain Name**: service.mywebsite.com

**DNS Target**: service.mywebsite.com.herokudns.com

***I need to point service.mywebsite.com to my heroku app through SSL.***

On my hosting website, I've created two CNAME records through DNS management:

- service -> service.mywebsite.com.herokudns.com.
- wwwservice -> service.mywebsite.com.herokudns.com.

And now, when I fire REST requests to service.mywebsite.com, they work, but when I fire to https://service.mywebsite.com, I get SSL errors. Also, when I visit https://service.mywebsite.com - there's a message, that the website does not support SSL connection.

My question is:

Is accessing service.mywebsite.com (launching REST requests) secure? Does it fire Heroku's SSL check? Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a CNAME - record as Heroku states in their guides

```
yoursubdomain CNAME service.mywebsite.com.herokudns.com
```